# Where to start with running a command line in PHP with CPanel hosting

Tags: php, shell, command-line, cpanel

I'm having a look at some PayPal scripts/code examples and a lot of them need a php script running via the command line.

I've never had to run anything from a command line in PHP before so don't know where to start at all. I don't know if I'm using the correct search terms as Google hasn't helped me answer.

Do I need to use a different application or is there something in cPanel I can use?

I get this error:

```
INSTALLATION ERROR: Please cd to the /home/site_name/public_html/site and run install.php
```

Comment: I think there is a way to SSH into the server using cPanel: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/CpanelDocs/ShellAccess

Comment: otherwise, download http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Comment: My cPanel has that disabled so I have had to go through PuTTY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SSH to access the server via the terminal:

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/CpanelDocs/ShellAccess

There's instructions on how to connect via PuTTY, then you can go to the directory where the PHP script is run it like:

php myPHPScript.php

Comment: So I need to download "PuTTY" (from here http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) and then connect to my hosting and go from there?

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right, executing php from the command line is pretty simply, the hardest part will be configuring putty to actually logging in :)

Comment: You were right, it's been a bit of an ordeal but thanks for getting me started! This little guide is quite handy for where to get started messing around with keys: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/ssh-keying-through-putty-on-windows-or-linux

Comment: Thank you, there just doesn't seem to be any resources/tutorials for complete beginners who don't even know what the correct terms or programs to use are so you've been very helpful :)

Comment: The link is now broken :(

Comment: Please either update link or remove it (it's broken)

Answer (score 0):

*If* your cPanel has the option to turn on SSH, do it. Then SSH into the server and run the commands -

```
cd /home/site_name/public_html/site
php install.php
```