# Running Shell script on cPanel

Tags: shell, ssh, cpanel

I want to deploy Django site on my server using cPanel, but everywhere I find that I've to use shell scripts. I've followed the official cPanel blog here on Shell Access: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/CpanelDocs/ShellAccess and also a SO post here: [Where to start with running a command line in PHP with CPanel hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339485/where-to-start-with-running-a-command-line-in-php-with-cpanel-hosting)

Still, I'm unable to do it. Putty never logins the connection. I'm really out of options here.

I've never run anything from a command line in cPanel before.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message you are receiving while using putty to login your server. Please make sure to select ssh before open.

And also telnet to port 22, to check it is open or confirm the ssh port to login.